# Schedule email notification to outlook contact using Python3.6

Tags: python-3.x, outlook, html-email, scheduler, outlook-restapi

I need to send weekly email notifications to corporate contact in outlook using Python3.6
I tried smtplib but it works for gmail, doesn't work for outlook contact.
I tried win32com.client, but it is not supported by Python version < 3.8
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Once you take the steps below, SMTP will function:
Open Outlook in a browser; click the gear icon for Settings in the top right corner; Then select "Options" from the drop-down list that appears. You can choose to "Let devices and apps utilise pop" by going to "Accounts," clicking "Pop and Imap," and then saving your choices.

here is the code snippet:

```
import smtplib

body = 'Subject: Subject Here .\nDear ContactName, \n\n' + 'Email\'s BODY text' + '\nYour :: Signature/Innitials'
try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 465)
#type(smtpObj) 
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login('me@outlook.com', "password") 
smtpObj.sendmail('sender@outlook.com', 'recipient@outlook.com', body) # Or recipient@gmail

smtpObj.quit()
```